# Can help in this piece of code with php language

Tags: php, html

How can I change this code

```
  **<video width="600" height="600" controls loop>
                <source src="./upload/posts/<?php echo $post['vidio'] ?>" type="video/mp4">
            </video>**
```

If in the database "in the post table" in "Video Column" was not a file
Do not show; And write "Not recorded for this video tutorial"

Comment: Put it inside an `if` statement that checks the condition you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `if` statement that displays one of the two choices.

```
if (empty($post['vidio'])) { ?>
    <span>Not recorded for this video tutorial</span>
<?php else { ?>
    <video width="600" height="600" controls loop>
        <source src="./upload/posts/<?php echo $post['vidio'] ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
<?php ;
```

Comment: It was so thankful. It was great.
answered